# MySQL - Updating a table IF record doesn't exist in another table

Tags: php, mysql

So, I'm writing a multi-query for my program that checks if a user has viewed a page or not. If they haven't viewed it, a record is created in a table named `views`, and then a record named `numViews` is updated in a table named `pages`, whereas if they've already viewed it, nothing happens.

I have the code written for the insertion of the record to `views`, which keeps all records unique. The problem I am facing is when it comes to updating a record in `pages`.

In Pseudo terms, the following is what I wish to be achieved:

```
if (record_exits_in_table_named_views == false) {
    UPDATE record IN pages
    INSERT record INTO views
}
```

The following is my query for adding a record:

```
INSERT INTO views
    (`pageID`, `viewerID`)
SELECT
    T.*
FROM
    (SELECT
        '.$this->pageID.' pageID,
        '.$_SESSION['userID'].' viewerID
    )
T LEFT JOIN
    views
ON
    views.creationID = T.pageID
AND
    views.viewerID = T.viewerID
WHERE
    views.viewerID IS NULL;
```

All help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You could let the database handle it: create an after insert trigger for the view table, that will update the pages-table or just calculate the value from the entries in views when you need them, so you don't need the value in pages at all (using the trigger would actually just be an optimization to speed it up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the update if i understand right ..should be this (not in clause)

```
 update pages
 set numViews  =numViews +1
 where (pageID, viewID) not in (select pageID, viewID from views)
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You use a similar `LEFT JOIN` in your `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE pages AS p
LEFT JOIN views AS v ON v.pageID = p.pageID AND v.viewerID = viewerID
SET p.numViews = p.numViews + 1
WHERE p.pageID = {$this->pageID} AND p.viewerID = {$this->viewerID}
AND v.viewerID IS NULL
```